# Define a preprocessor directive constant conditionally

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

How can I make it work?

In `C#` code:

```
if (condition)
{
    #define CONSTANT
}
```

I tried doing something through `<DefineConstants Condition="'$condition'"></DefineConstants>` in a project file's `<PropertyGroup>` section.

But it won't work because the condition will be based on something that we know AFTER the program is built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; your runtime code (`if`) cannot affect compile-time directives (`#define`). You need to use another approach. Maybe use a `static readonly bool` that you calculate once at runtime - the JIT on up-to-date .NET versions will *usually* treat this the same as a `const`, and perform dead-code removal appropriately during the JIT process, making `if (SomeStaticReadOnlyOrConst)` *almost* the same as `#if SOME_SYMBOL`.